# How do I load images from a folder using vue-gallery?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a gallery with vue-gallery, but I'm not exactly sure how to load images from a folder. 
It should also be noted, I'm using the nuxt.js framework.

I've tried just adding the images one by one, but that would be unconventional since I would like to be able to upload images to that folder, and not worry about having to add images to an array. I know node.js, but I'm not sure how to get files in folders without fs.

I am using nuxt.js with vue and vue-gallery installed.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <gallery :images="images" :index="index" @close="index = null"></gallery>
    <div
      class="image"
      v-for="(image, imageIndex) in images"
      :key="imageIndex"
      @click="index = imageIndex"
      :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image + ')', width: '300px', height: '200px' }"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VueGallery from 'vue-gallery';

  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        images: [
          'https://dummyimage.com/800/ffffff/000000',
          'https://dummyimage.com/1600/ffffff/000000',
          'https://dummyimage.com/1280/000000/ffffff',
          'https://dummyimage.com/400/000000/ffffff',
        ],
        index: null
      };
    },

    components: {
      'gallery': VueGallery
    },
  }
</script> 

<style scoped>
  .image {
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

This is the that I'm using, which displays those dummy images. I am unsure how to read from a folder and add them into the `images` array that vue-gallery` requires.

Expected results: vue-gallery displays the images properly from the folder.
There is no error, it's just me not knowing what to do. lol

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working using this

[Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWgQK.png)

Comment: Don't put links to images to code. Do directly write code here using the dedicated code tags.